# Slow query on index_together fields in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I've got controller input data uploading management command in Django 2.2.3 with PostgreSQL server 10.7. After profiling I've found that from 5 seconds execution time on example data in sum after 1750 iterations 3 seconds are spent on `existing_variable_value = VariableValue.objects.get(variable_id=variable.id, record_id=record.id)` source string. It is really bad and strange.

In `VariableValue` model `Meta` subclass there is statement `index_together = unique_together = ['record', 'variable']` (both are foreign keys). If I execute `explain analyze select * from analytics_variablevalue where record_id = '1' and variable_id = '2';` in PSQL console I see `Index Scan` i.e. index is used. Also PSQL shows `execution time: 0.063 ms`, if I multiply it on 1750 variable values count in source data file it is 110 ms, which is far less than 3 seconds that I get in Django code.

Could anybody help me explain such behaviour and optimize my code?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a latency between your client and your database. Even 2ms round-trip-time will add 3.5s running time to 1750 invocations of a query.

You might have to batch your queries. Maybe with Django's [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) or something similar.

---

Even on local connection query latency is significant.

```
$ psql 
psql (11.5)
Type "help" for help.

tometzky=> \timing on
Timing is on.
tometzky=> select 1;
Time: 0.931 ms
tometzky=> select 1;
Time: 0.461 ms
tometzky=> select 1;
Time: 0.494 ms
tometzky=> select 1;
Time: 0.462 ms
```

Comment: Both client and server are on one host currently